# How to check if a table contains a rule set's conditions

Tags: java, data-mining

I am doing some data mining coding and I want to classify the rule induced form a table set depending if the rule condition is classified correctly based on the existing data set.

Let say I have the following data set:

```
[ Temperature Headache Nausea Flu ]
  high        ?        no     yes 
  very-high   yes      yes    yes
```

and my algorithm induced the rule

```
(Headache, yes) -> (Flu, yes)
```

In order to check if my rule set is correct I want to check the classification by going through every data set and check if the headache is yes and flu is yes.

I was able to do it easily, but what if I have different conditions in my rule such as:

```
(Temperature, high) & (Nausea, no) -> (Flu, yes)
```

How can I check both conditions at the same time?

I am saving my conditions in a `HashSet`, and the data set is an `ArrayList` of `HashSet`s where each row is a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `containsAll` this should work the exact same way.

It's not the fastest or smartest approach, bug for tiny data sees it's okay to use `ArrayList<HashSet<String>>` here. A better approach would use an inverted index.